# Regex for numeric numbers range

Tags: c#, html, regex

Is there a regex that allow if number start with 1 the length will be 10 and if number start other than 1 length is 9.

Examples:

- `012345678` (since it starts with 0 the length required is 9)
- `1234567890` (since it starts with 1 the length required is 10)

I try  `^[1][0-9]{8,9}` but it only do for the `b` condition.

I need a regex that will do both conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `^[1][0-9]{8,9}` pattern only matches strings that start with `1` and then have 8 or 9 digits, but can end with any text after these patterns.

You may use

```
^(?:1[0-9]{9}|[02-9][0-9]{8})$
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%28%3F%3A1%5B0-9%5D%7B9%7D%7C%5B02-9%5D%5B0-9%5D%7B8%7D%29%5Cr%3F%24&i=012345678%0D%0A1234567890&o=m)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:` - start of a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do):

  - `1` - `1` digit
  - `[0-9]{9}` - any nine ASCII digits
- `|` - or

  - `[02-9]` - any ASCII digit other than `1`
  - `[0-9]{8}`  - any eight ASCII digits
- `)` - end of the group
- `$`  - end of string.